# Postgresql - postgres@localhost failed FATAL: role does not exist

Tags: postgresql, homebrew

I just installed postgres (with brew) and started it with `pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l logfile start`

I now try to connect to it in the terminal but get the following:

Connection to PostgreSQL - postgres@localhost failed
FATAL: role "me" does not exist

The issue might be that I first installed postgres.app and then didn't get it work right and then removed it.

Comment: The account you should be using initially is `postgres` and it should not require a password.

Comment: I run 'su postgres' then `initdb /usr/local/var/postgres9.5 -E utf8` but I get `creating directory /usr/local/var/postgres9.5 ... initdb: could not create directory "/usr/local/var/postgres9.5": Permission denied`

Comment: for some reason when I run initdb I got the var/postgres dir created with user root

Comment: actually, I just checked the users on my mac, I have a postgresql user, I think its because I started with postgres.app and then switched to brew and it just confused things, not sure what to do now @Nicarus

Answer (score 3):

You don't show what you typed and as which user you did it, but from the error message I'd say that you should add `-U postgres` to the `psql` invocation.

Comment: enjoy the easiest bounty ever.. probably

Comment: Well, if it did the trick for you, that's mission accomplished. If not, please tell me more details.

Comment: I can award in 15hrs

Comment: for some reason I am now getting `FATAL:  role "postgres" does not exist` any easy way to resolve?

Comment: Did you `DROP USER postgres` or something? If you have no superuser in the database, you'll have to stop the server, start it in single user mode as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27777076/accidently-removed-postgres-default-superuser-privileges-can-i-get-it-back/27778321#27778321), then look with `SELECT * FROM pg_authid` and recreate the user if necessary.