# Creating Superuser with non of my already users are superuser at Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I ended up with non of my users is a superuser! how can I get at least on of them superuser ? Postgresql !

Comment: Read the instructions properly, the first time you can validate yourself as a superuser via system credentials and then create a separate superuser account if that's desirable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accidently removed postgres default superuser privileges - can I get it back?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27777076/accidently-removed-postgres-default-superuser-privileges-can-i-get-it-back)