# Accidentally removed super user privilege from user: postgres on postgres 10. How to get it back without re installing?

Tags: linux, postgresql, postgresql-10

I accidentally removed the super user privilege from user: postgres. I don't know how to get another super user. I stopped the postgres service and tried logging in with single-user mode:

```
/usr/pgsql-10/bin/postgres --single -D /var/lib/pgsql/10/data
```

I get this error:

> "root" execution of the PostgreSQL server is not permitted.
>   The server must be started under an unprivileged user ID to prevent
>   possible system security compromise.  See the documentation for
>   more information on how to properly start the server.

In Linux, how can I start Postgres in single-user mode so I can fix the super user privilege?

Edit: I used this link for reference, but I'm getting the error mentioned above.
[Accidently removed postgres default superuser privileges - can I get it back?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27777076/accidently-removed-postgres-default-superuser-privileges-can-i-get-it-back/27778321)

Comment: Just do it as user `postgres`, not `root`, and it will work like a charm.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe: Thanks for your comment. I did a variation of this, and that fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I combined solutions from these three links:

1. [Accidently removed postgres default superuser privileges - can I get it back?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27777076/accidently-removed-postgres-default-superuser-privileges-can-i-get-it-back/27778321)
2. [Restoring the superuser account on the postgres server](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/61781/restoring-the-superuser-account-on-the-postgres-server)
3. [“root” execution of the PostgreSQL server is not permitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28311825/root-execution-of-the-postgresql-server-is-not-permitted)

After stopping the postgresql service, I ran this command:

```
sudo -u postgres /usr/pgsql-10/bin/postgres --single -D /var/lib/pgsql/10/data
```

1. /usr/pgsql-10/bin/postgres is the location of my postgres binary
2. /var/lib/pgsql/10/data is the location of my postgresql conf

This allowed me to access single user mode, where I just typed this command:

```
ALTER USER postgres SUPERUSER;
```

So if anyone is experiencing the same scenario as me, please give the posted command a try.

Answer (score 1):

just adding this for postgresql 12 (Ubuntu) and possibly up

```
sudo -su postgres /usr/lib/postgresql/12/bin/postgres --single -D /etc/postgresql/12/main
```